# Number of permutations such that adjacent elements don't differ by more than $K$

Tags: combinatorics

Given $N$ and $K$, I need to count number of permutations of $1, 2, 3,\ldots, N$ in which no adjacent elements differ by more than $K$. How do I approach this problem?

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: I am trying to count the number of permutations by hand, but it is too cumbersome.

Comment: Here is one estimate: There are $N!$ permutations.  Each has $N-1$ adjacent pairs.  These must all come from $(N-1)+...+(N-K)$ of the $N(N-1)/2$ pairs, so my estimate is $N!{(N-1)+...+(N-K)\choose N-1}/{N(N-1)/2\choose N-1}$.

Comment: This is [OEIS A249631](https://oeis.org/A249631). I note there are no formulae there, only a couple routines that generate/filter/count, so I wonder if there are in fact any other methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question that appeared in a contest i.e Codecraft 2015 organised by IIITH and its editorial is available [here](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/16099). You can also submit your code in the gym.

Basically you require DP + Bitmask.You need to keep track of last_used element and all other elements included so far.You can do it using recursion and it will require memoization to optimize it.